# How do I save my work on the michael hartl tutorial and pick off where I left off later?

Tags: ruby, save

Is there such as saving and continuing where I left off?  Or do I have to do the whole process in one go and/or not allowed to shut down my computer.  I'm really new to coding and my slow progress is going to cause me to take breaks, but I've been just keeping my computer on so I can just pick up where I left off.

Thank you and I really appreciate your feedback.

Austin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial at the very beginning he explains about using `Git` and `Github`. [It](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) is used to store the applications' code.

Comment: So how would one go about picking up where they left off? What line of code would one use to load up the applications code on a fresh startup of the computer?  Thank you so much!

Comment: by means of using text editor (sublime2 for instance).